# get active tab id in button click event inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular js bootstrap modal window in which I have two tabs. The footer being the same, how do I identify and send the id of the active tab to my submit button event handler?

```
<div class="modal-body">
<tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="One" id="one"></tab>
    <tab heading="Two" id="two"></tab>
</tabset>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="doSomething(activeTabId)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-click` you can use `select()` which is what the `angular-bootstrap` documentation uses for `tab` selections. Another note to consider is that the `tabset` directive and the `tab` directive creates an isolated scope, therefore, you need to assign the `activeId` to an object within the scope for it to be accessible within those isolated directives.

Note: Here's an **[FAQ](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)** about scopes.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyTabController">
  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="One" id="one" select="tab.activeTabId = 1"></tab>
    <tab heading="Two" id="two" select="tab.activeTabId = 2"></tab>
  </tabset>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .controller('MyTabController', function($scope, $window) {

    // store tab related data in a scope object
    // to avoid problems with isolated scopes
    $scope.tab = {};

  });
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])

  .controller('MyTabController', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.tab = {};

    $scope.submit = function(activeId) {
      $window.alert(activeId);
    };

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.13.3" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyTabController">

  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="One" id="one" select="tab.activeTabId = 1"></tab>
    <tab heading="Two" id="two" select="tab.activeTabId = 2"></tab>
  </tabset>

  <hr> active id: {{ tab.activeTabId }}
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit(tab.activeTabId)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">
      Alert Active Id
    </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: From the Angular UI Bootstrap team:  good answer.  I would suggest changing "...you _can_ use..." to "...you _should_ use..."